# MS Excel: Show length dynamically on changing cell value

Tags: excel, vba

There is a string value in `cell A2` which should show its length in `cell B2`. When I change the string in `cell A2` and press enter, the length in `cell B2` will also change as per LEN function. But I need length to show "dynamically" when typed in the cell by pressing F2. Below is the Excel VBA that I tried

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A2:A2")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

    Range("B2").Value = Len(Range(Target.Address))
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible when typing in a cell. The closest solution I can think of is to create an ActiveX TextBox instead, then reading the length of its value when it's changed like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Range("A1") = Len(TextBox1.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: I have around 5K records, so I cant put ActiveX text box